# Access SQL Editor - "You may have entered an operand without an operator"

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet, iif

I am VERY bad at the JET/Access SQL and it frustrates me.  I am getting the above stated error when entering the code below and I can't see why - It's basically just a big IIf/then statement.  It seems to be highlighting the portion "PB" if that is any help:

```
REQUIREMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION: IIf([REQUIREMENT_TYPE]="01","Warehouse Sales Orders",IIf([REQUIREMENT_TYPE]="04","Warehouse Sales Orders",IIf([REQUIREMENT_TYPE]="TB","Warehouse Sales Orders",IIf([REQUIREMENT_TYPE]="KE","Dedicated Sales Orders",IIf([bal]=0,"Warehouse Sales Orders",
IIf([REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY] = “A60380029”, "Warehouse Sales Orders,
IIf([REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY] = “A60380021”, “Warehouse Sales Orders,
IIf([REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY] =  “A60380020”, “Warehouse Sales Orders,
IIf([REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY] =  “A60380007”, “Warehouse Sales Orders,
IIf([REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY] =  “A60380001”, “Warehouse Sales Orders,
IIf([REQUIREMENT_TYPE]="PB","Forecast","Excess")))))))))))
```

Comment: You seem to have some curly double quotes in there, which Access won't accept.  Fix that, and try running it again.

Comment: They are also called 'smart quotes' and Access does not recognize them. If you type code in app like Word, then copy/paste, those characters can be picked up. Some copy/paste from web pages will cause same.

Comment: If you are making this call from VBA code, then consider using the `switch` function, [see here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php).

Comment: Can use Switch() function in query as well.

Comment: wow! I had no idea about that, I was indeed editing it in Word as it is easier to see.  Amazing and thanks.  I am an SSMS guy so maybe I will edit in there from now on.

Comment: Also part of `"Warehouse Sales Orders,` strings have no closing quotes

Comment: The SQL `IN` operator would also be convenient here.

Comment: @SergeyS. - I did realize that as well, I am so very bad at JET SQL...thank you

Comment: @CPerkins - I actually had that originally - I am pretty proficient in regular SSMS syntax...I changed it as part of thinking that maybe it wasn't supported in JET/Access SQL.  Thanks for the input though - always appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Applying suggestions in comments, consider:

```
REQUIREMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION: Switch([REQUIREMENT_TYPE] IN("01","04","TB") OR [bal]=0 OR
[REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY] IN("A60380029","A60380021","A60380020","A60380007","A60380001"),"Warehouse Sales Orders",
[REQUIREMENT_TYPE]="KE","Dedicated Sales Orders",
[REQUIREMENT_TYPE]="PB","Forecast", 
TRUE,"Excess")
```